# What is the procedure to report a bug/crash about a Steam game?

Tags: steam

I've some games that crashes in Steam, but I can't find to whom I should report the bug. Should I go to the developer's page or to some obscure Steam form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be both. You can't always know for sure if the crash come from Steam or the game itself. It happened to me a while ago when Amnesia A Machine For Pig wouldnt start on Steam. I contacted both the Editor and Steam support in order to get an answer (I even got the same answer from both side).

- If you have an issue with steam : [Create a new ticket on Steam Support](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php)
- If you want to report to the game editor : [Try here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_cat.php?id=11) to find your game and on the steam support page (of the game) you have a link to the editor's support page or form.